# select record from table which is table itself is a result of another query

Tags: mysql, sql

i have following mysql query:

```
select opportunity_id from (select join_table from relationships where lhs_module='Accounts' and rhs_module='Opportunities')
```

I got following error message:
 Every derived table must have its own alias

Is it possible to select record from table which is table itself is a result of another query?

Comment: Is `opportunity_id` a column of `join_table`? Please post your schema.

Comment: Your current query has multiple problems.  Please post your schema and ideally some sample data.

Comment: query result of select join_table from relationships as t where lhs_module='Accounts' and rhs_module='Opportunities'  is accounts_opportunities

Comment: I want to use accounts_opportunities as a table name

Comment: Leaving the error to one side, it's not clear what the query is trying to achieve. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You are implying that you want some dynamic SQL but you might not really need it.  Schema, data, expected output please.

Answer (score 0):

Why do You need to join to the same table to only use 'where' condition?

```
select opportunity_id from  relationships where lhs_module='Accounts' and rhs_module='Opportunities'
```

This should work for You unless You had other intenstions then what we can see so far.

Comment: I believe the OP is asking how to fetch the table name for the first `SELECT` query from the table `relationships`.

Comment: select join_table from relationships as t where lhs_module='Accounts' and rhs_module='Opportunities' is accounts_opportunities will output accounts_opportunities. accounts_opportunities is the table name which is i am going to use for the first select